# Compare (multiple parameters) and update another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this block of code:

```
Sub CompareTwoRanges()

    Set myRange1 = Application.Range("Sheet1!$A:$A")
    Set myRange2 = Application.Range("Sheet2!$A:$A")

    For Each c1 In myRange1
        For Each c2 In myRange2
        
        Set Stock1 = c1.Offset(0, 1)
        Set Stock2 = c2.Offset(0, 4)
        Set supplier = c2.Offset(0, 8)

            If c1.Value = c2.Value And supplier = "Google" And Stock1.Value <> Stock2.Value Then
  
            
             c2.Offset(0, 4) = Stock1
            c2.Offset(0, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do is...

If Sheet1 A1 = Sheet2 A1 and supplier = google and Sheet1 A2 <> Sheet2 A5
Then Sheet2 A5 = Sheet1 A2.

I hope that makes sense so far. However, my problem is that this is taking forever/causing excel to crash, both sheets have around 100k rows.

Any solutions would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare 1M cells with another 1M cells that make 5E11 rounds. That really takes time :) So first try to define the operating ranges more exactly, like

```
Dim lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
lastrow1 = Range("Sheet1!a1000000").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Range("Sheet2!a1000000").End(xlUp).Row

Set myRange1 = Application.Range("Sheet1!$A:$A").Resize(lastrow1, 1)
Set myRange2 = Application.Range("Sheet2!$A:$A").Resize(lastrow2, 1)
```

that will reduce the number of loops to 5E9. But it will take time, too.

Next you can move processing to memory by reading the values to arrays and do the same logic within memory. This way you can save time on avoiding Excel interaction in every single loop that needs a lot more time.

So i would do something like this:

```
Dim arr1(1 to lastrow1, 1 to 6), arr2(1 to lastrow2, 1 to 6)
Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long
Dim sh2 As Worksheet

Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

' read data to arrays
i1 = myRange1.Row   ' 1st row of myRange1
i2 = myRange2.Row   ' 1st row of myRange2
For Each c1 In myRange1
    arr1(i1, 1) = c1.Value
    arr1(i1, 2) = c1.Offset(0, 1).Value
    i1 = i1 + 1
Next

For Each c2 In myRange2
    arr2(i2, 1) = c2.Value
    arr2(i2, 2) = c2.Offset(0, 4).Value
    arr2(i2, 3) = c2.OFfset(0, 8).Value
    i2 = i2 + 1
Next

' Now compare values

For i1 = myRange1.Row To lastrow1
    For i2 = myRange2.Row To lastrow2
        If arr1(i1, 1) = arr2(i2, 1) And arr2(i2, 3) = "Google" And arr1(i1, 2) <> arr2(i2, 2) Then
             arr2(i2, 4) = arr1(i1, 2)
             arr2(i2, 5) = 1            ' indicate need to write to Excel
             Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

' finished comparision, update Excel

For i2 = myRange2.Row To lastrow2
      If arr2(i2, 5) = 1 Then
           With sh2.Cells(i2, 4)
              .Value = arr2(i2, 4)
              .Interior.ColorIndex = 38
           End With
      End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks. I get a the following error:

Compile error:

Constant expression required

Here: Dim arr1(1 To lastrow1, 1 To 6), arr2(1 To lastrow2, 1 To 6)

If I change it to ReDim it runs but it doesn't update anything.

Comment: There are simpler ways to read ranges into an array. For example: `Dim arr() As Variant, arr2() As Variant` `arr = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns("A:B").Value` `arr2 = Sheet2.UsedRange.Columns("A:I").Value`. Might be helpful to read/process in chunks if it's too much memory.

Comment: Adding ReDim and adjusting 1 of the OffSets works. Only takes a minute to complete.

Thank you everyone for your input!